# Grep search on ONE LINE only?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I am using Bash to find the dimensions of a matrix. Here is my code to get the number of elements in one row, however it prints out for the whole file. I just need the number of elements in ONE ROW.

```
grep -oP  "\^I" $1 | wc -l
```

Here is what the $1 is referring to:

```
1^I2^I3^I4$
5^I6^I7^I8$
```

For some reason, it is printing out 9 instead of 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure it is not printing 6 right now with your example?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
cat $1 | head -n 1 | sed 's/\^I/\n/g' | wc -l
```

I take the only the first row using `head`, replace every column delimiter with a newline using `sed`, then pipe that to `wc`.

Comment: suggestions: 1) no need to use cat, use `head -n1 $1` 2) you can directly ask sed to act only on first line, so no need of head at all 3) OP wants `3` as output, not `4`

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed before calling grep to isolate one specific line of your file:

```
sed -n '1p' file | grep -oP "^I" | wc -l 
        ^
        ^
# will print the 1st line, 2p will print the second line etc
```

on your input it gives:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`

```
$ awk -F'\\^I' 'NR==1{print NF-1}' $1 
3
```

- `-F'\\^I'` use `^I` as field separator
- `NR==1` first line only
- `print NF-1` since the question is about counting number of `^I`, need to print number of fields minus one

also, if `$1` is argument being passed to shell script, use `"$1"` as good practice

and a guess, this is actual data OP is working with

```
$ cat ip.txt
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
$ cat -A ip.txt
1^I2^I3^I4$
5^I6^I7^I8$
$ # exit to avoid unnecessary processing of other lines
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{print NF-1; exit}' ip.txt
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's:\^I:\n:g; q' | wc -l
         ^       ^
         |_______|_______ change all ^I to \n
                 |_______ quit after first line
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.